# There is an exercise about async Callbacks an I am trying to solve it but I get error. How can I solve it?

Tags: javascript, callback, asynccallback

Write a function called `printAsyncName`, which will take as parameters a callback and a string (which will be name). The callback function will simply print "Hello".
The `printAsyncName` function will have to execute the callback function after an interval of 1 second. After an interval of 2 seconds, we must print the name that we take as a parameter.

Tips:

- The `setTimeout` method will be useful
- The callback function must be an arrow function, can you also explain why?

```js
function printAsyncName(sayHello, name) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(name);
  }, 2000);
  let hello = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Hello");
  }, 1000);
  sayHello(hello);
}

printAsyncName("Jack");
```

And this is the error I got:

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: sayHello is not a function
    at printAsyncName (/Users/arya/Downloads/es-73/exercise.js:8:3)
    at <anonymous> (/Users/arya/Downloads/es-73/exercise.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:17:47)
```

Comment: I think your code is incomplete. Can you just put your whole code.

Comment: @TusharShahi They did, they just put the code fence in the wrong place.

Comment: The first argument to `printAsyncName` is supposed to be the `sayHello` callback function. The second argument is the name.

Comment: Read your code out loud. I am calling printAsyncName  with the sting 'Jack'. The function printAsyncName has two parameters, a function sayHello and a string name.....

Comment: Looking at your requirements, even if callback is not an arrow function it will work. Can you recheck if you have pasted the right requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function printAsyncName(name, callbackFunction) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(name);
  }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        callbackFunction;
  }, 1000);
}

callback = () => console.log('hello');
printAsyncName('John', callback())
```